# PHP: Relative to absolute URLs in curl'ed html

Tags: php, curl

I am retrieving a simple HTML page using curl in PHP:

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/server");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and `include`ing it in a file on my website:

```
<?php include('curlingCodeAbove.php');?>
```

I want to replace the relative URLs in the `curl`ed HTML with absolute URLs. I am familiar with [Change a relative URL to absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342785/) but I have tried unsuccessfully to insert that solution into this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself. Set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` flag.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/server");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#",'$1http://mydomain.com/$2$3', $result);
echo $result
?>
```

While it's probably bad form to accept your own answer, hey, I'm the one who figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is search for `="/` and replace with `="http://www.example.com/`

for example:

```
$replaces['="/'] = '="http://www.example.com/';
$output = str_replace(array_keys($replaces), array_values($replaces), $output);
```

I have not checked this but it should do what you need.

Comment: The concern is not changing relative URLs to absolute ones in isolation. The answer to that is linked in the original question. The concern is how do I work that in to the curling code, since I can't find a way to modify what is sent by `curl_exec` to the second file before it is displayed?