# preg_match: javascript url string

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, src

I am trying to construct a REGEX pattern, to convert **relative** URLs to **absolute** URLs in javascript scripts.

Example: I would like to replace ALL instances of the following (taken from js script):

```
url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
```

And return the following:

```
url('http://example.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
```

Example pattern that works for HTML tags ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590220/5762867)):

```
$pattern = "#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#"
```

Preferred use of this pattern:

```
$result = preg_replace($pattern,'$1http://example.com/$2$3', $result);
```

The closest I have managed to guess (unsuccessfully) is:

```
$pattern = "#(url\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([\"'])#";
```

Comment: You don't have an `=`s in your search string, or not in the form `url =`.. Try `(url\(["'])(?!http)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've used (thanks to help from andlrc and chris85):

```
$result = preg_replace("#(?<=url\((['\"]))(?!https?)#",'http://example.com/', $result);
```

Comment: The `[s]` is requiring an `s` did you mean to make the `s` optional?

Comment: Yes please. How do you recommend I make the 's' optional?

Comment: Use `s?` the question mark will make `s` match zero or one time

Comment: Like this `https?`. Also your second and third capture groups are empty, replacing with `http://example.com/` will yield the same result. https://eval.in/590456 The `?` makes the previous character, or group, optional.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for you:

```
/(?<=url\((['"]))(?!http)(?=.*?\1)/
```

With replacement:

```
http://example.com/
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG8xV4/2)

The above regex will match the position just after `url('` where the quote can also be a double quote.

```
(?<=...) # is a positive lookbehind
(?!...)  # is a negative lookahead
(?=...)  # is a positive lookahead
\1       # refers to capturing group 1, in this case either ' or "
```

Note that lookbehinds isn't supported in JavaScript but are in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help!

Comment: @LeenRemmelzwaal I hope I have given enough information on how this regex works, you can consider looking up lookarounds on google :-)

Answer (score 0):

My testing shows that this will work:
`/url\\(['\"](?!http[s]?:\\/\\/)(.+)['|\"]\\)/`

So your replace should look like:

`preg_replace("/url\\(['\"](?!http[s]?:\\/\\/)(.+)['|\"]\\)/",'http://example.com/$1', $result)`

Not a regex master tho - so take this with a grain of salt

Comment: A character class is a list of optional characters. So the `s` doesn't need to be in one and the `['|\"]` doesn't need the `or` the `or` actual makes the pipe optional as well. You also could capture the first quote type and use a back reference for the second to make sure you match. e.g. https://regex101.com/r/sY5sN2/1 (if using single quotes for the regex encapsulation, if double the `\`s need to be doubled)