# Find absolute path to image from relative path with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, path, relative-path, absolute-path

There are similar questions ([PHP: Find images and links with relative path in output and convert them to absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457693/php-find-images-and-links-with-relative-path-in-output-and-convert-them-to-abso)) but I'm not sure they solve this problem.

I am developing a jQuery plugin which could be installed in any directory. It uses images which also could be installed in any directory. The path to the image is set in a data attribute like so:

```
<div id="pr-preview"
    data-img-src="img/example.jpg"
    data-savepath="img/resized/">
</div>
```

This is passed to a PHP file with and AJAX function. In my PHP file I need to get the dimensions of the image like so:

`list($width, $height) = getimagesize($this->data['img']);`

But obviously I am getting an error:

`getimagesize(img/example.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...`

The PHP file resizes the image and needs to save it to the predefined save path (`data-savepath="img/resized/"`). I'll also face the same problem here.

So taking into account I won't know where this plugin will be installed when in use, how can I ensure these paths are correct?

If possible I would like to avoid having to put the full paths in the data attributes.

**UPDATE**

This is the plugin folder structure. This folder could be installed anywhere in `public_html`. And the images directory could be anywhere too:

```
public_html/
            img/
               example.jpg
            pluginName/
                  css/
                  js/
                  php/
                     PluginName.php // where getimagesize() is called
```

Comment: Did you try `realpath()`?

Comment: Or eventually something with `pathinfo()`?

Comment: Yea @Daenu, thanks. I have tried `realpath()` with no luck - if it can't resolve the path to begin with I guess this won't work.

Comment: If the `img` directory is relative to your php script you can just define a constant `define('IMAGE_PATH', __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'img/resized/');`. Where `__DIR__` will return the directory of the file, not the calling script.

Comment: @frz3993, good call, but the img directory could be anywhere - see my update. Hope that clarifies it a bit. Can't believe something so simlpe can be so tricky!

Comment: @user3065931, this will depend on your web/code structure. If the `PluginName.php` is called from a front controller like `index.php` and the path in `data-img-src` is relative to the front controller, concatenating `./` at the front of `$this->data['img']` will resolve to the file. Without the absolute path given, it needs to be relative to something right ?

Comment: If it can be anywhere, i.e. you don't know anything about the images' location, you're lost. Your only chance would be to search for them. Try glob() or a system call to find (if the webserver's on linux).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code could help. It will recursively search through the directories starting at document root until it finds one called "img". You can prepend the returned path ("`$imgs`") to your image filename, then.

```
<php
define('IMG', 'img');
$docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$imgs = find_img($docroot) . '/';

function find_img($startdir){
    if(basename($startdir) == IMG){
        return realpath($startdir);
    }
    elseif(is_dir($startdir)){
        $results = glob($startdir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach($results as $dir){
            if(basename($dir) == IMG){
                return realpath($dir);
            }
            else{
                return find_img($dir);
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
}
?>
```

This assumes, of course, that you at least know what the images' directory is called and that there is only one location. If this is not the case you'd have to change the code e.g. so that it searches for directories with `.jpg` inside, though that'd be highly unreliable.