# converting mixed(absolute,relative) to absolute link

Tags: php, parsing, relative-path, absolute-path

i have this php script which works well an convert almost all pages nicely but in few pages it is unable to convert relative url to absolute url.it is giving wrong result for below links.

```
      $url = 'http://www.lowridermagazine.com/girls/1201_lrms_cat_cuesta_lowrider_girls_model/photo_01.html';

  // Example of a relative link of the page above.
  $relative = 'photo_01.html';

   // Parse the URL the crawler was sent to.
   $url = parse_url($url);

  if(FALSE === filter_var($relative, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
   {
    // If the link isn't a valid URL then assume it's relative and
   // construct an absolute URL.
    print $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].'/'.ltrim($relative, '/');
  }

else

{
 $relative;
 }
```

it works nicely for http://www.santabanta.com/photos/shriya/9830084.htm url but fails in above url.
any idea where i am doing mistake

Comment: @the-pixel-developer  please help in ur code.its working for few sites but few are not working as sain question

Comment: @choise your this answer is not working in my case  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342785/change-a-relative-url-to-absolute-url